# Why doesn't initializing a std::vector<T> initialize T?

Tags: c++, vector

Why is the default constructor for `A` not called when I initialize an `std::vector` like so?

```
std::vector<A> vec; //Doesn't call constructor
vec.push_back(A(2)); //Calls constructor
```

I don't understand this, can somebody explain in great detail please?

Comment: It's not called because you are initializing a `std::vector`, not an `A`.

Comment: i know that v is not an A but when type of vector is  A type how  vector v will be created , how compiler will allocated resource for it ? my point is how compiler will allocate resources or it will be allocated later ?

Comment: If you can ask the size of class by sizeof(A) without creating an Object of A , then compiler can allocate an array of A without even construction it.

Comment: @user5905343 The vector is initially empty, contains no `A`, so there is nothing to construct.

Comment: Why would you need to construct an `A` to construct an *empty* vector?

Comment: @user5905343: compiler will not call `A()` because `vector`'s initialization doesn't create object of type `A`. You can assume that memory for `vector`'s content is allocated when needed. Also memory allocation doesn't need any constructors to be called, it is just memory reservation. Constructor of `A` is called only when `A` is being constructed.

Comment: Think about it, if A doesn't have a default constructor, the line std::vector<A> vec; will not compile. This will be a huge limitation.

Comment: Can you explain *which* object of type `A` you would expect to be initialised?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz , no question is about resource allocation how compiler allocate space for it

Comment: I don't understand the down vote, the question is legit, after all, if you create your own trivial version of std::vector (for exercise), you will probably end up with a call in the default constructor (assuming you will use new T[] to allocate the memory). So, it seems a natural question to ask. Btw, the answer is to split the allocation and construction of the object it two separate operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you construct vector `v` it contains no `A` objects (so there is no need to call a constructor).  As you populate `v`, you explicitly construct `A` objects and these are then copy or move constructed into the memory in the vector.

There are never any default constructed `A` objects, so the default constructor is never called (your code would compile fine if you marked it `= delete`).

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
std::vector<A> vec;
```

initializes a `std::vector`m not an `A`. Although it holds instances of `A` is hasn't been initialized in a way that would cause instances of `A` to be created.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `vector<A>`, you only initialize the underlying vector infrastructure, with enough memory to hold a bunch of `A` element, but no `A` is initialized at that time, so no A ctor has to be called.

When you push back a (temporary) `A(25)`, the temporary is first created from its simple ctor, then it is copied (or moved) in the vector internal array, and destroyed.

That explains the order and time of apparition of your messages.